Metadata not showing up in Phantom Wallet
I minted and added metadata to my old version SPL fungible token and the meta data shows up correctly on all explorer sites but its not showing in phantom. Does someone know if this is an issue with phantom wallet?
Does it need to be minted with metaplex for it to work or something?
Pumpfun uses the old token program and they show up fine no problem. Any ideas? Thank you.
I verified that my link to the json file works and this is the format
{
"name": "Token",
"symbol": "TOKEN",
"description": "MY TOKEN",
"image": "https://url.ipfs.w3s.link",
"website": "https://website.com",
"twitter": "https://x.com/xxxxxx",
"telegram": "https://t.me/xxxxxx",
"extensions": {
"twitter": "https://x.com/xxxxxx",
"telegram": "https://t.me/xxxxxx",
"website": "https://website.com"
}
}

This is not an issue, give Phantom amsome time to index your token and it will show up after a while.

Are you sure about this? Pump fun tokens get added right away. Also 2022 get added right away as well.

i would wait as well. Might be related to the fact that you had it in your wallet before the update. try to send it to another wallet (like solflare), i guess it should work
